# Converter texto de div para número

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando pegar o texto dessa estrutura:

```
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
```

E gostaria que me retornasse apenas o `71,90`.

Porém na estrutura em que criei, não consigo tirar o "R$" do texto e fazer o reconhecer apenas os números.

Como poderia fazer essa conversao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue o valor do elemento, depois faça um `.split` com `javascript`

```
var str = $("#our_price_display").html(); //pega valor todo
var res = str.split(" "); //seu valor você pega no res[1]

alert(res[1]);
```

Comment: Diego, veja este link do meta quando puder. [O que fazer com o “espero ter ajudado” no final das respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5458/18246)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar regex.

```
/\d+,\d+/g
```

Onde:

- `\d+` = busca por números
- `,` = inclui a vírgula
- `/g` = global (em toda a string)

Exemplo:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var regex = /\d+,\d+/g;
  var texto = $("#our_price_display").text();
  var valor = regex.exec(texto);
  $("#resultado").text(valor.join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
<br/>
<span id="resultado"></span>
<br/>
<button>Só valor</button>
```

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância...
 $(function(){
          var valorDaDiv = $("#our_price_display").empty('/\d+,\d+/g');   
          var myInteger = parseInt(valorDaDiv); // 
           console.log(myInteger);
 });

Seria mais ou menos isso?

Comment: @JulioRodrigues atualizei a resposta com a explicação e um exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var text = document.getElementById('our_price_display').innerText;

// APENAS DIGITOS E ,
var number = text.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');
console.log(number);

// NUMERO PARA FLOAT (numeros presupostos que estão corretos em R$ > 1000,00)
var number = number.replace(',', '.');
console.log(parseFloat(number));
```

```html
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('our_price_display').innerHTML;
var numero = texto.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = numero;
```

```html
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: caracaaa man,muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var price = document.getElementById('our_price_display');
var formattedPrice = price.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');

console.log("Valor formatado:", formattedPrice);
```

```html
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
```

O regex vai limpar da string tudo que não for numérico ou vírgula.

Answer (score 0):

As respostas acima já solucionam bem seu problema, mas se quiser dar uma olhada nessa biblioteca [http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/](http://accounting.js).

Já utilizei para converter texto em USD em um jogo, é bem simples de utilizar e possui diversos formatos monetários.